# SQL Server : function return column values that can be used in where clause?

Tags: sql-server, sql-function

I want to fetch record from table with `WHERE IN` clause like this:

```
Select * 
From Table_A
Where table_id IN (Query X that returns multiple or single id)
```

Now I want to move X query to a SQL Server function because it will use multiple places and want to call query like that:

```
Select * 
From Table_A
Where table_id IN dbo.function(parameters)
```

Is it possible to do this? If yes then which will be the type of function (scalar or table function)?

Comment: Yes it's possible but I think it's better done with a join. Subselects can be real performance-killers for SQL-server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i think in this way u need to pass

```
CREATE FUNCTION function_name(@inputparams ...)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN  SELECT id FROM table WHERE @inputparams...
go
    select * 
    FROM    table
    WHERE   table_id IN ( SELECT column_name FROM function_name(inputparametes) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fncName (@params ...)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN  SELECT id FROM tableName WHERE @params...
go
SELECT * FROM query WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM fncName(@params...))
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [answer]. You should provide some information why your code solves the problem.
Code-only answers aren't useful for the community.